# How to display last 4 numbers in an int?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

i have an int field that i want to display its last 4 numbers in jsf page, please advise how to accomplish that.

Comment: Are you familiar with the *mod* operator? It's remainder after division. In Java the mod operator is the % character, so number % 10000 will yield the last four digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the last four digits of a number, use the modulus operator:

```
int someInteger = 23421984;
int last4digits = someInteger % 10000;
// last4digits = 1948;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) for that, this is also [supported](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaik.html) in [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) using the modulus operator `%`.

```
<p>Last 4 numbers: #{bean.number % 10000}</p>
```